# Salesfroce-Vimeo how to connect via oauth?

Tags: salesforce, vimeo

I want to embed vimeo videos in my Vf page. I am trying to embed this with the link but it says access denied. Means it needs and authorization.

Can any body please suggest me how to d this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sounds like the video isn't public? I'd have thought your real problem is some settings on Vimeo — I highly doubt you want your users to create accounts / login to Vimeo, and doubt you really need to store credentials for your own account either.

[I've just created a public sites page to show that if the Vimeo settings are set up right that it can be embedded without a login](http://funkytest-developer-edition.ap1.force.com/test/apex/VimeoEmbed).

The entire page code is below, note I had to add `="true"` to the various full screen attributes in order for Salesforce to save the file correctly.

```
<apex:page >
  <iframe src="http://player.vimeo.com/video/38991709?title=0&amp;byline=0&amp;portrait=0" width="400" height="225" frameborder="0" webkitAllowFullScree="true" mozallowfullscreen="true" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
    <p>
      <a href="http://vimeo.com/38991709">ANGRY BEARD</a> from <a href="http://vimeo.com/user9441946">TKSH! Films &amp; Stop Motion</a> on <a href="http://vimeo.com">Vimeo</a>.
    </p>
</apex:page>
```

*The video is not mine, it's just one I found on the Vimeo home page a moment ago*

Comment: A quick question.. can i have to do some type of authentication using vimeo API???

Comment: If you need authentication then yes, Vimeo offer standard oAuth 1 authentication so you shouldn't have any problems performing login — they have more information at http://vimeo.com/api/docs/authentication